# Forcing screensaver lockout time for all users in Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, lock-screen, screensaver, administration

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Unity.  Is there a way to force the screensaver lockout time using an admin account?

By default each user can change their lockout time.  I need to be able to prevent this.

Thanks,
Aaron